# Case insensitivity does not work

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I cant figure out why my searches are case sensitive.  Everything I've read says that ES is insensitive by default.  I have mappings that specify the standard analyzer for indexing and search but it seems like some things are still case sensitive - ie, wildcard:

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "wildcard": {
        "name": {
          "value": "Rae*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This fails but "rae*" works as wanted.  I need to use wildcard for 'starts-with' type searches (I presume).

I'm using NEST from a .Net app and am specifying the analyzers when I create the index thus:

```
  var settings = new IndexSettings();
  settings.NumberOfReplicas = _configuration.Replicas;
  settings.NumberOfShards = _configuration.Shards;
  settings.Add("index.refresh_interval", "10s");
  settings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, AnalyzerBase>("keyword", new KeywordAnalyzer()));
  settings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, AnalyzerBase>("simple", new SimpleAnalyzer()));
```

In this case it's using the simple analyzer but the standard one has the same result.

The mapping looks like this:

```
name: {
    type: string
    analyzer: simple
    store: yes
}
```

Anyone got any ideas whats wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: With more recend version of ES (2.3) you can use Completion Suggester for this.

Comment: i have same issue. even when tried "query_string" it does not work in ES 5.1, but it worked in 2.3. !!!!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/wildcard-query/),

> "[The wildcard query] matches documents that have fields matching a wildcard expression ***(not analyzed)***".

Because the **search term is not analyzed**, you'll essentially need to run the analysis yourself before generating the search query. In this case, this just means that your search term needs to be lowercase. Alternatively, you could use [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "name:Rae*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is a good idea to use query_string, isn't that a low-level fn?