# Elasticsearch synonyms case sensitive results

Tags: jdbc, elasticsearch, lowercase, synonym

Could anyone give me a tip what I'm doing wrong.
I'm trying to set up elasticsearch this way

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "custom",
                        "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                        "filter" : ["en_US", "lowercase", "synonym"]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                    },
                    "en_US" : {
                        "type" : "hunspell",
                        "locale" : "en_US",
                        "dedup" : true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "jdbc" : {
            "properties" : {
                "Title" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "search_analyzer" : "synonym",
                    "index_analyzer" : "standard"
                },
                "Abstract" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "search_analyzer" : "synonym",
                    "index_analyzer" : "standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My synonym.txt file contains

```
beer, ale, lager, cark ale
Lithuania, Republic of Lithuania, Lithuanian
```

So it's time to try out my analyzer:

```
http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_analyze?text=beer&analyzer=synonym&pretty=true
```

It works as expected and returns me

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "beer",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "ale",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "lager",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "cark",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "ale",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 4,
    "type" : "SYNONYM",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

However, querying this:

```
http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_analyze?text=Lithuanian&analyzer=synonym&pretty=true
```

Would return only:

```
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "lithuanian",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 10,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case insensitivity does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17266830/case-insensitivity-does-not-work)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522863/elasticsearch-case-insensitive-query-string-query-with-wildcards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During Analysis the token filters are applied  in the order specified. 
So in the above case "Lithuania" is first converted to lowercase "lithuania".
Since the synonym file does not contain this case version of the token no synonym conversions occur.
This section in [elasticsearch guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/synonyms-analysis-chain.html#_case_sensitive_synonyms) talks more about this.

There are two ways you could to go about this depending on the use case either change the order of token filters in the custom analyzer to :

```
  "synonym" : {
         "type" : "custom",
         "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
          "filter" : ["en_US", "synonym","lowercase"]
   }
```

The above would still be case sensitive but the conversion would be consistent with the above 
synonyms.txt

Or you could make all the synonyms in analysis/synonym.txt to be lowercase and keep the same analyzer settings as specified in the question.
Example:

```
  beer, ale, lager, cark ale
  lithuania, republic of lithuania, lithuanian
```

Comment: That's what I actually did. Making every synonym lowercase was the easiest and quickets solution to get things working. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind this creates mismatches with words like CAT (medical scan) and cat (animal).